# What is Daniel's mother's profession in The Karate Kid?

Tags: plot-explanation, karate-kid

In The Karate Kid, Daniel and his mother move from New Jersey to southern California.

He tells the new kid he meets that his mother works in computers or something.

> **Daniel**: My mom got a job with some company out here. Rocket Computers. Flight of the Future. I don't know.
>
> **Freddy**: I never heard of it.
>
> **Daniel**: It's up and coming.

But then later on they are at a restaurant next to Cobra Kai, his mother is dressed nice and it seems like she's talking about working at the restaurant.

> Guess what. I'm going to be trained as a manager. Isn't that great? The program's two nights a week. As soon as a spot opens up, you're in. And the benefits! **I could never get them working in computers.** They pay for everything.

What are we to take from this? Did something happen to the computer job? Was Daniel just confused or am I?

Comment: *"I'm going to be trained as a manager."* - That doesn't sound like she's going to work at a restaurant. It sounds more like she's getting promoted within her company. Are you really sure she's talking about the restaurant they're currently in? Could you clarify a little more what makes you think so?

Comment: Hi @NapoleonWilson! In the scene, she's not actually eating. It looks like she just asked him to meet her there and bought dinner for him. She's also dressed pretty nice, as if she just went to an interview or she's at work right now. (I guess she could have just left the office.) Finally some woman yells at her "Lucille let's go here they come!" If you look carefully, the woman is holding menus and looks like a hostess. Is this woman her boss/coworker? I don't know.

Comment: I found a clip on YouTube of the restaurant scene. I noticed even more dialogue that makes it clearer, and will edit the question. https://youtu.be/-LWUcg1vLEg?t=89

Comment: "I'm going to be trained as a manager." is exactly the kind of thing a prospective restaurant manager would say. In fact, the _only_ management training I've ever personally been to was for Burger King.

Comment: Feel free to add some of this information into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From following two sources,

[This](https://www.80stees.com/blogs/1980s-pop-culture-trivia-lists/26-facts-about-the-karate-kid-that-you-probably-dont-know) and [this.](http://mentalfloss.com/article/57156/30-facts-about-karate-kid)

Rocket Computers went bankrupt when Daniels mom arrived in California and soon found a job at restaurant.

As she shares with Daniel:

> “They went bankrupt!...[But] listen to this. I walk out of Rocket with the beginning of Excedrin headache one through ten about to come on, and I’m going back to the car when this woman comes flying out of this restaurant, The Orient Express, and she’s screaming, ‘I quit! I quit!’ Right behind her is this guy and he’s yelling just as loud, ‘You can’t quit! You’re fired!’ It’s one minute to noon, people are coming in to lunch, I’m the first but only applicant — I got the job!”

The above mentioned dialogue was not in the movie but in the novelization by B.B.Heller.

You can find it on [google books.](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=T76K3dTAhLIC&dq=The%20Karate%20Kid%201&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=Orient)

Comment: It would help to clarify that the quoted text is from the original script, and not included in the film. As written, it sounds like that dialog is in the film.

Comment: @GendoIkari: Added google books source.